# Gettext automatic comments generation

Tags: php, internationalization, comments, gettext, po

I'm doing i18n for a php project using gettext. I'd like to use the [automatic comment feature](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#PO-Files) to give hints to translators when translating long phrases replaced by id. What I want to obtain is the following po file

```
#: full-path-to-file/index.phtml:3
#. a very long text which should replaced by _('foobar')
msgid "foobar"
msgstr ""
```

In this way the translator can see what he should translate when he see the key `foobar` using POEdit or some analogue tool in the programmer comment box.

I've tried with this code but it doesn't work

```
<?php
/// TRANSLATORS: a very long text which should replaced by _('foobar')
_('foobar');
?>
```

Am I missing something or automatic comments just don't work for php?

Even Wikipedia [mentions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_gettext#Programming) this feature, I've tried to copy their example in a C file, but I cannot get it working even with C. The command line I've used is

```
xgettext -C -o - main.c
```

But the generated output is

```
#: main.c:16
#, c-format
msgid "My name is %s.\n"
msgstr ""
```

So I'm definitely missing something, should I use any `xgettext` flag or particular version to enable this feature.

Comment: And in case you try to extract from javascript using --language=Python, append a hash # to the comment start, meaning you start comments like //#, this way xgettext will extract the translation comments correctly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make `xgettext` extract comments from your source, you need to pass an argument to tell it what comments to look for.

From the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#index-g_t_002d_002dadd_002dcomments_0040r_007b_002c-_0040code_007bxgettext_007d-option_007d-183):

> ‘`-c[tag]`’ 
>   ‘`--add-comments[=tag]`’
>
> Place comment blocks starting with
>   tag and preceding keyword lines in the output file. Without a tag, the
>   option means to put all comment blocks preceding keyword lines in the
>   output file.

Passing `-c/` or `--add-comments=/` as an argument will make it recognize the "triple slash" format.

Comment: @John Flatness - any idea why this doesn't work with .js files in Python mode? More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052844/extract-translator-comments-with-xgettext-from-javascript-in-python-mode

Comment: Note that if you use `-c/` to up comments such as `/// hint to translator`, it will also pick `// x/y is always > 2 here`, too. The xgettext will emit `#. y is always > 2 here` into the .pot file for this example.