# Inserting translator notes/comments in PHP files

Tags: php, localization, gettext, poedit, xgettext

I am working on translating an application I am developing. I have strings like:

```
echo _("Welcome to my site");
```

I can then use the command line to create a `.po` file from all the PHP files in a particular directory by doing:

```
find . -iname "*.php" | xargs xgettext
```

However, when I import this into Poedit, I see a box called "Notes for translators". This may be useful sometimes, however I can't figure out how to populate it. What code do I need to add to my PHP file so that xgettext will add notes to translators?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665274/gettext-automatic-comments-generation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the help of xgettext shows:

-cTAG, --add-comments=TAG   place comment blocks starting with TAG and
                                preceding keyword lines in output file
  -c, --add-comments          place all comment blocks preceding keyword lines
                                in output file

so add in your file by example:

// COMMENTTAG: This is another block comment that will be extracted by xgettext.

And run xgettext with --add-comments=COMMENTTAG

Comment: Works great. I don't suppose there is a way to not start the actual outputted comment with `TAG` is there? I didn't see that in the documentation anywhere.

Comment: You could use --add-comments without a tag, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665274/gettext-automatic-comments-generation

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that too, but I'm not sure if somewhere in my code I have some sort of other unrelated comment that I wouldn't want showing up.

Comment: only comment blocks preceding keyword lines are used

Answer (score 3):

In Poedit, you can go to File/Preferences/Extractors menu, select the appropiate language you are extracting (PHP in your case), and then click Edit. Here you can see the command used to extract translations:

`xgettext --language=PHP --add-comments=TRANSLATORS: --add-comments=translators: --force-po -o %o %C %K %F`

You can see and modify here how additional translator comments are parsed. You can use `// TRANSLATORS: your notes` or `// translators: your notes` in the line before you use the `_('your text')` to add these comments to the code. Example:

```
// translators: 'practice' is a verb, used on a button as an action.
echo _('practice');
```

Only one `--add-comments` parameter will be active at a time, so `// translators:` is set as the default in Poedit.